# how to remove all the section breaks from a word file

Tags: c#

I want to remove all the Section Breaks from my word file, I'm using this code, but it removes only page breaks, not Section Breaks.

```
app.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Execute("^m", false, false, ref o, ref o, ref o, true, ref findWrap, true, "", ref replace, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "^12" as your replacement string. You can see a list of replacement codes [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/find-and-replace-text-or-other-items-HA001230392.aspx#_Toc282602052). Also read the note about ^m : it finds or replaces section breaks *when the Use wildcards option is turned on*.

Comment: `^m` also works when "Use Wildcards" is active. Which would be the first `ref o` in that line, I guess.